# Php create unique timestamp based session_id after login returns true

Tags: php

Is there a way to id a session in PHP based on the session_start timestamp?
The session needs to be collision free because I haven't id the session for a system am building and one session overrides the other every time I do it on the same browser....

```
<?php
//Login credentials processing code goes here and then we get to the point where login returns true and then we are to start a session 
... 
if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
//start the session 
session_start() ;
//Here is where I need that code that can generate unique session  based on the timestp of the session start... 
?>
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you won't just use `session_regenerate_id` on login? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: It will create a unique session if for different users using the same browser?

Comment: I need the complete code,  what goes into the bracket please 

Comment: session_regenerate_id("???? ") ;

Comment: I need a timestamp based one because there is no day two users will access the system from the same device at the same time, its collision free

Comment: How about: Read that manual page about it, and sessions in general. Comprehend what sessions are about and the ways you use them. Figure out what exactly you want (because its entirely unclear here), and create some code which gets you close to the end result you are aiming for. If you get stuck there, come back with more code and the problem, and desired result. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Purpose is to avoid collision of sessions bro